# SQL Query to get the related data in different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 5 table,

```
user, plan, achievement, user_plan, user_achievement
```

The strucutre

```
User
id
name

Plan
id
name

achievement
id
name
*planID

user_plan
*planid
*userid

user_achievement
*achievementid
*userid
*createDate
```

And I use Codeigniter (Doesn't matter , what I would like to have is the mysql query)

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Actually, for each plan , there is a list of achievement, if it is not achieved, it is not stored at the user_achievement, so how can I get "for each user, get 1) his name 2)the plan he joins, and 3)the achievement he achieve and not achieve (need to highlight the achieved)"?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with `JOIN` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join

```
 $this->db->select('i.id,u.name,up.planid,p.name as planname,ua.achievementid,ach.name as ach_name');
 $this->db->from('user as u');
 $this->db->join('user_plan as up','up.userid = u.id','left');
 $this->db->join('plan as p','p.id = up.planid','left');
 $this->db->join('user_achievement as ua','ua.userid = u.id','left');
 $this->db->join('achievement as ach','ach.id = ua.achievementid','left');
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` between tables `user`, `plan`,`achievement` and `user_achievement` like below

```
select u.name as username,
p.name as planname,
a.name as achivementname
from User u
left join user_achievement ua on u.id = ua.userid
and ua.createDate is not null
left join achivement a on ua.achievementid = a.id
left join Plan p on a.planid = p.id
```